# Добавить данные из формы на страницу при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Вопрос в следующем:
Необходимо после заполнения данных в форме (имя, фамилия, номер телефона) нажать на кнопку "сохранить контакт" и вывести данные под формой.
При клике на кнопку "удалить контакт", соответственно удалить данные из списка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно уточнить, где сделана форма: сайт, десктопное приложение и т.д. Если есть пример кода или верстки, то было бы неплохо его приложить в сообщение.

Comment: Одностраничник. Верстать еще не садилась, хочу сначала с js разобраться

Comment: @ЕкатеринаМезенцева, мне кажется, нужно сначала сначала сверстать хотя-бы какой-то каркас (можно со всякими bootstrap'ами), а потом на это навешивать js

Comment: "Вопрос в следующем:" - непонятна суть вопроса, -1.

Comment: @Igor,  вы к логике предложения придираетесь или вам и правда непонятно, что я спрашиваю?

Comment: Мне непонятно, что Вы надеетесь увидеть в ответе. Ваши три строчки - это не вопрос, а задание, причем в самом общем смысле. Что Вы сами сделали?

Comment: @Igor, я надеюсь увидеть совет от знающих js и jquery людей, с помощью какого решения можно это реализовать. Сама в js не разбираюсь. Обычно я пользуюсь готовыми jquery решениями, но для данного случая в сети ничего не нашла. Если для того, чтобы мне помочь необходимо сначала увидеть каркас вёрстки, то значит я сверстаю и прикреплю к вопросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом общем виде это может выглядеть так:

```js
$('#form').submit(function(e){ //по клику на сабмит
   e.preventDefault(); //предотвращаем отправку формы
   //создаём внутри таблицы ячейки и выводим туда данные из формы
   $('table').append(
     '<tr><td class="name">'+$('#name').val()+'</td><td class="surname">'+$('#surname').val()+'</td><td class="phone">'+$('#phone').val()+'</td><td class="delete"><b>X</b></td></tr>');
   $('input').not('[type="submit"]').val(''); //очищаем поля формы
});

$('table').on('click', '.delete', function(){ //по клику на крестик удаляем строку
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.name, .surname, .phone, .delete {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.delete {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
Имя <input type="text" id="name" /><br /><br />
Фамилия <input type="text" id="surname" /><br /><br />
Телефон <input type="text" id="phone" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить контакт" /><br /><br />
</form>
<br />
<hr />

<table>

</table>
```

Но здесь надо понимать, что после перезагрузки страницы все данные в любом случае исчезнут (неважно, удаляли Вы их крестиком или нет). Если данные нужно сохранять, то для этого придётся использовать либо базу данных на сервере, либо (на худой конец) localStorage в браузере